# Polkit rule for systemd template unit files

Tags: systemd, polkit, units

I'm trying to figure out how to write a polkit rule for a systemd template file. The rule is triggered when I use the actual service that will be instantiated (`openvpn-client@miami.service`) but not when I leave out the instance identifier string (`openvpn-client@.service`).

Here is the complete working rule:

```
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
  if ( action.id == "org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units") {
    if (action.lookup("unit") == "openvpn-client@miami.service" && subject.isInGroup("wheel")) {
      var verb = action.lookup("verb");
      if (verb == "start" || verb == "stop" || verb == "restart") {
        return polkit.Result.YES;
      }
    }
  }
  polkit.log("action=" + action);
  polkit.log("subject=" + subject);
});
```

My hunch is that I could use javascript regex to just glob the string between "@" and ".service" but I can't quite figure it out.

My vpn provider has many possible servers, each with its own config (referenced by the openvpn-client@.service template unit file), so I'd really like to not have to write a polkit rule for each instance of the template.
Thanks a lot!

**Update:**

I solved this according to my hunch above, using regex to test for template file. This is maybe unsafe?

```
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
  if ( action.id == "org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units") {
      var instance = /openvpn-client@[a-z]+.service/.test(action.lookup("unit"));
    if ( instance === true && subject.isInGroup("wheel")) {
      var verb = action.lookup("verb");
      if (verb == "start" || verb == "stop" || verb == "restart") {
        return polkit.Result.YES;
      }
    }
  }
  polkit.log("action=" + action);
  polkit.log("subject=" + subject);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I will but I don't have the reputation yet.

Comment: You can't answer your own question ? Hmmm... Here's an upvote anyway...