# Polkit rule for systemd template files - how to

Tags: systemd, polkit

I am trying to use polkit to allow specific user to start/stop/restart specific services. Those services are defined via systemd template, so for example user can run this command:
`systmctl stop my-daemon@<parameter>.service`. Parameter is alphanumeric string, user defined.
This polkit rule works perfectly:

```
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
if (action.id == "org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units" &&
    action.lookup("unit") == "my-daemon@foo1.service" &&
    subject.user == "user1") {
    return polkit.Result.YES;
}
```

However, it's for *static* parameter, *foo1* and it won't work with any other parameter.

I have tried regexp to make the rule generic, here are some examples of critical, third line of the rule:

```
action.lookup("unit") == "my-daemon@*" &&
action.lookup("unit") == "my-daemon@[:alnum:]+" &&
action.lookup("unit") == "my-daemon@foo[0-9]" &&
```

None of the above works. Seems to me polkit does *not* allow regexp in this place.
I have read [Polkit rule for systemd template unit files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/351052/polkit-rule-for-systemd-template-unit-files), but it isn't a solution for me - author is testing filename, not directly unit name. What am I doing wrong?

This is continuation of my previous question [Controlling systemd system service as user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/546556/controlling-systemd-system-service-as-user), however before I had old systemd and it wasn't possible to write even the static rule. Now it should be possible and I am failing miserably.

```
OS Suse 12.5
Polkit version 0.113
Systemd version 228
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uff. Solved this one, thanks to the help of another programmer who sent links to good manual pages: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/latest/polkit.8.html
and mainly https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions which explains relevant things from JavaScript programming language.

As expected, I only changed one line that deals with name of the service.

```
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
if (action.id == "org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units" &&
    RegExp('my-daemon@[A-Za-z0-9_-]+.service').test(action.lookup("unit")) === true &&
    subject.user == "foo1") {
    return polkit.Result.YES;
}
});
```

RegExp() is a function, and .test in the middle of the line tests the regular expression in ' ' to another string, which is function asking for name of the service. Hope it helps someone else stuck on similar issues.